# How can I build a hash of hash from Hash of Hash of array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have following hash of hash of array with me:

```
Hash["signin"]["elementname"]["ids"]` -- here ids are "macid" and "winid"
```

Its structure is like elementname has two kind of ids `macid` and `winid`.

On runtime when I pass a parameter say `mac` then I am trying to build a hash from a existing hash which would have only `macid`.
So that, I am trying to convert a `Hash["signin"]["elementname"]["ids"]`.

Comment: Maybe you should describe the structure of the hash you need to obtain.

Comment: Can you amend your question to include some sample data and some sample output?

Comment: For example:

I have a hash called `common_ids`

`common_ids
=> {"signin"=>
  {
   “company_txt"=>{“mac_id"=> mac_id_1, “win_id"=> win_id_1},
   "username_txtbx"=> {“mac_id"=>”mac_id_2”, “win_id"=>”win_id_2”}
   }
}`

Comment: so, when I try to get the data:

`common_ids["signin"]["company_txt"] ` It gives me hash of ids ` {"mac_id"=>nil, "win_id"=>nil}`

And I am trying to do is:
When I want to execute the script, I am passing parameter which would be like “Mac” or “WIN”. 
Now I am building the hash to set the value from one of the id “MAC” or “WIN” to the 

`common_ids["signin"]["company_txt”]`

So that, if I try to fetch the Mac_ids then my new hash would be like:

`common_ids["signin"]["company_txt"] => mac_id value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
Hash[common_ids.map { |a|
  [a[0], Hash[a[1].map { |b|
    [b[0], b[1]['mac_id']]
  }]]
}]
```

You need to do the Hash[...] part because the map method on a hash turns it into an array of key-value pairs.

Hopefully that code works for you.  It worked for me in irb.  You may want to rename the a and b variables to something that makes more sense.

**Here's some explanation:**

When you call .map on a hash, it provides each value as a [k, v] array, it expects the contents of the block to evaluate to a [k, v] array, and the result returned by .map is an array of [k, v] arrays.  Hash[...] is used to turn that style of array back into a hash (see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).

For

```
common_ids = {"signin"=> { "company_txt"=>{"mac_id"=> "mac_id_1", "win_id"=> "win_id_1"}, "username_txtbx"=> {"mac_id"=>"mac_id_2", "win_id"=>"win_id_2"} } }
```

here is what happens:

The first level block (with parameter a) gets

```
a = ["signin", { "company_txt"=>{"mac_id"=> "mac_id_1", "win_id"=> "win_id_1"}, "username_txtbx"=> {"mac_id"=>"mac_id_2", "win_id"=>"win_id_2"} }]
```

It calls map on the second entry of that array (the value part of the key-value pair) using the second block (with parameter b), which first gets

```
b = ["company_txt", {"mac_id"=> "mac_id_1", "win_id"=> "win_id_1"}]
```

It returns

```
["company_txt", "mac_id_1"]
```

Then it gets

```
b = ["username_txtbx", {"mac_id"=>"mac_id_2", "win_id"=>"win_id_2"}]
```

It returns

```
["username_txtbx", "mac_id_2"]
```

The result of this inner map is

```
[["company_txt", "mac_id_1"], ["username_txtbx", "mac_id_2"]]
```

Calling Hash[...] on this gives

```
{"company_txt" => "mac_id_1", "username_txtbx" => "mac_id_2"}
```

This is then given as the second element of the array for the outer map, resulting in

```
["signin", {"company_txt" => "mac_id_1", "username_txtbx" => "mac_id_2"}]
```

If you had a second top-level element of common_ids, it would result in the same processing.  When the outer map call completes, you have

```
[["signin", {"company_txt" => "mac_id_1", "username_txtbx" => "mac_id_2"}], ...]
```

where the ... represents where additional top-level elements of common_ids would go.

Calling Hash[...] on this gives

```
{"signin" => {"company_txt" => "mac_id_1", "username_txtbx" => "mac_id_2"}, ...}
```

where the ... represents any additional top-level key-value pairs in the form k => v.

Hopefully that explanation helps.

Comment: is Hash[] part includes the map method which we need to define it. As I am beginner to ruby, could you please guide me through it.

Comment: I am not able to create the Hash[ ] part which you suggested. could you please guide me.

Comment: What do you mean you can't create it?  It's like calling a method but with square brackets. Can you give some more details?

Comment: i did it in this way:   `common_ids = common_ids.map {|k,v| [k.to_s, v]}`   and when I used your above code, I am getting all values as nil for all keys. Below is the output:   `{"signin"=>
  {"company_txt"=>nil,
   "username_txtbx"=>nil}}`

Comment: Hash[...] isn't a data structure, it's a static method on the Hash class that acts like an array index

Comment: can you give me your email, so that we can discuss on it. if it is ok to you.

Comment: My code only used one parameter in the block passed to map. You should try doing it like I did with one parameter and treating that parameter like a [k,v] array

Comment: I'm not seeing a private message option in the mobile app and I don't want to post my email in a public place. I'm also going to be signing off for the day pretty soon